# Jsoup extracting the element for given text without knowing the element tag

Tags: jsoup

Using Jsoup, With out knowing what element tag to search for, I need to get the element which has a given text.
For example; given this html and the text "me".

```html
<span>me</span>
<label>my self</label>
<tr class="ego">and I</tr>
```

how can I get back the element

```
<span>me</span>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`getElementsContainingOwnText`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsContainingOwnText-java.lang.String-) to get an element that contains a partial match, or [`getElementsMatchingOwnText`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsMatchingOwnText-java.lang.String-) if you want to match on a regular expression. You can use a regex for a complete match --

```
    doc = Jsoup.parse(...);

    // Match only elements whose text is exactly "me"
    Elements elements = doc.getElementsMatchingOwnText("^me$");
    for (Element element : elements) {
        // manipulate element
    }
```